# Chai spies and async calls not call once

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I m building an application in which I need to test some callback behaviours inside of an express callback resolution.

Actually, it looks like :

```
const callbackRender = (httpResponse, response) => {
  console.log(httpResponse) // logs the good httpResponse object
  if (httpResponse.content.content) response.send(httpResponse.content.content)
  else response.render(httpResponse.content.page)
}

const callback = (injector, route) => {
  return (request, response) => {
    const ctrl = injector.get(route.controller)
    const result = ctrl[route.controllerMethod](new HttpRequest())
    if (result.then) {
      return result.then(res => callbackRender(res, response))
    } else {
      callbackRender(result, response)
    }
  }
}
```

The two failing tests look like :

```
it('should call the callback render method when httpResponse is a promise', (done) => {
      const mock = sinon.mock(injector)
      const ctrl = new UserControllerMock()
      const routes = routeParser.parseRoutes()
      mock.expects('get').returns(ctrl)
      const spy = chai.spy.on(callbackRender)
      callback(injector, routes[3])(request, response).then((res) => {
        expect(spy).to.have.been.called.once
        mock.verify()
        mock.restore()
        done()
      })
    })

    it('should call the callback render method when httpResponse is not a promise', () => {
      const mock = sinon.mock(injector)
      const ctrl = new UserControllerMock()
      const routes = routeParser.parseRoutes()
      mock.expects('get').returns(ctrl)
      const spy = chai.spy.on(callbackRender)
      callback(injector, routes[1])(request, response)
      expect(spy).to.have.been.called.once
      mock.verify()
      mock.restore()
    })
```

It seems that chai-spies isn't able to detect that my callbackRender function is called in the callback method.

The fact is that, when I log my method, I pass inside of it each time I need it to do.

Does anybody has an idea ?

EDIT : The request  / response definition in beforeEach

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    request = {
      body: {},
      params: {},
      query: {}
    }
    response = {
      send: () => {
      },
      render: () => {
      }
    }});
```

Comment: Where are you setting up the `request` and `response` arguments in your test?

Comment: I've editted my post to show you beforeEach hook

Comment: Ok. My advice is to ditch the spies and just inspect the result of calling `callback`. When you use spies you are tightly coupling your test to the internals of your function. Should you choose to refactor your internals, you need to update all your spies and that can be a lot of work. Instead, just test the expected result, passing in stubbed values to model the expected behaviour of the app that is passing data in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spies/stubs/mocks can only work if they can *replace* the original function (with a wrapped version), *or* if they get passed explicitly (which isn't the case in your code).

In your case, `callbackRender` isn't replaced (it can't be, due to the `const` but also because it has no "parent" object in which it can be replaced), so any code that will call it (like `callback`) will call the original function, not the spy.

A solution depends on how exactly your code is structured.

If `callback` and `callbackRender` are located in a separate module together, you might be able to use [`rewire`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) to "replace" `callbackRender` with a spy.

However, one caveat is that `rewire` also can't replace [`const` variables](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire#limitations), so your code would have to change.

Comment: Nop, they are in the same module. In fact, the callbackrender exists only to factor some code and avoid duplication of sending the response

Comment: @Skahrz yeah, what I meant was that you would have a separate module in which _both_ would be located :)

Comment: ooh ! great idea ! I ll try this one